# Why doesn't istream::operator>> have an overload that takes a char?

Tags: c++, stream

[istream::operator>>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) has an overload that takes any kind of variable to write into, except for `char`. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two sets of overloads for both `std::istream` and `std::ostream`. The ones for numeric types, manipulator types, and buffers are defined as member functions while the ones for character-based I/O are global functions. In addition to the character-based overloads, there are overloads for different standard classes like `std::string` and `std::complex`. You yourself can even implement different overloads for different custom classes.

Answer (score 1):

There are [non-member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) and [member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) overloads for `operator>>`. The char overloads you are looking for are function templates, whereas the member overloads are non-templated. For example:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& operator>>( basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& st, CharT& ch );
```